# Installing Meteor on Raspbian

Tags: meteor, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm looking for a guide to installing Meteor, including NodeJS and MongoDB, on Raspbian.  I have seen a couple of online articles, however, they are 3-4 years old.

Comment: It doesn't need to be `Raspberry Pi` or `Raspbian` specific instuctions. Why don't you use any `Debian` based distro instructions?

Comment: Would `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` work on Raspbian?  I thought there was a problem with running on ARM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer and posting it here for others who may have the same question.

Part of these instructions are from:
https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor

Install meteor for ARM processors on Raspbian:

```
cd $HOME

git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor.git

$HOME/meteor/meteor --version
```

Create a symlink

```
cd /usr/bin

sudo ln -s $HOME/meteor/meteor meteor
```

Test your install

```
cd $HOME

meteor create hello-world

cd hello-world

meteor
```

Open your browser to http://localhost:3000 to see the app working.

Comment: This work but you get an outdated meteor project. With The universal you have a 1.3.4 meteor app, whereas 1.5 meteor was release sometimes ago. I write this but I don't have alternative solutions...